# Java - How to access an ArrayList that is inside a method's scope, from another method?

Tags: java, scope, hashmap

Yes, I know that's impossible; but the problem is that I really need to do it. I'll explain the whole trap:

```
public class MainMethods {

ArrayList arrayOfValues; // << PROBLEM

HashMap<String, Object> matrix = new HashMap<String, Object>();

void sendKeyToMatrix(String key) {
    arrayOfValues = new ArrayList();
    matrix.put(key, arrayOfValues);
}

void attachValueToKey(Object object, Object value) {
    matrix.put((String) object, arrayOfValues.add(value));
}

void removeFromMatrix(String key) {
    matrix.remove(key);
}}
```

That's my class and those are my methods. I created a HashMap with the key being a String and its value being an Object; pretty simple.

The real problem is with what I intend to do with this "Object" as a value. I have a GUI and a button that calls the "sendKeyToMatrix", and another one that attach a value to it, both from textFields. Since the ".put()" method for HashMaps requires an Object and I must create only the key first, the second argument is "null" or THE PROBLEM (ArrayList).

The perfect solution:

```
public class MainMethods {

HashMap<String, Object> matrix = new HashMap<String, Object>();

void sendKeyToMatrix(String key) {
    ArrayList arrayOfValues = new ArrayList();
    matrix.put(key, arrayOfValues);
}

void attachValueToKey(Object object, Object value) {
    matrix.put((String) object, ghostOrigin.add(value));
}

void removeFromMatrix(String key) {
    matrix.remove(key);
}}
```

When I call the "sendKeytoMatrix" with the button, it creates a key with an empty ArrayList as its value. This key is added to my JList. Then, when I call the second button (Considering what is selected in the JList), I add an element to the ArrayList:

Code for the second button:

```
btnInsertContent.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            mainMethods.attachValueToKey(mainList.getSelectedValue(), textContent.getText());
            mainCombo.addItem(textContent.getText());
            System.out.println(mainMethods.matrix);

        }
    });
```

The second argument of the "attachValueToKey" receives the String given by the textField, and I reach the big problem:

I can't add it to the ArrayList inside the "sendKeyToMatrix" method, which is obvious, but that's a big problem, because if I declare the variable as a field up there (So that I can access it down in the other scope), I get wrong and esoterically misterious results that are unknown to me.

Resuming this in a simple question: How to access the variable inside the other method?

If I declare the variable inside the "attachValueToKey", it will create an ArrayList inside of the ArrayList every time the button is pressed.

Well, I thank you all for the help. Probably there must be a way to summon the solution through Object Oriented Magic, with instances and the like.

Comment: Your post is too long that can't be read, please be very specific on telling the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should answer your question I suppose:

```
void attachValueToKey(Object object, Object value) {
    ArrayList a = matrix.get((String) object);
    a.add(value));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For learning purposes, I'll leave here the solution I found thanks to Lazarus:

```
public class MainMethods {

HashMap<String, Object> matrix = new HashMap<String, Object>();

void sendKeyToMatrix(String key) {
    ArrayList<Object> arrayOfValues = new ArrayList<Object>();
    matrix.put(key, arrayOfValues);
}

void attachValueToKey(Object object, String value) {
    ArrayList<String> arrayInMatrix = (ArrayList<String>) matrix.get(object);
    arrayInMatrix.add(value);
    matrix.put((String) object, arrayInMatrix);
}

void removeFromMatrix(String key) {
    matrix.remove(key);
} }
```

Action of the Button:

```
btnInsertContent.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            mainMethods.attachValueToKey(mainList.getSelectedValue(), textContent.getText());
            mainCombo.addItem(textContent.getText());
            System.out.println(mainMethods.matrix);

        }
    });
```